# Hibernate - Updating an ID of a parent in a child without updating parent?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, entities

I couldn't find the answer or didn't phrase this question properly. If you guys know... let me know :-)

I have a parent which has children....

on the child, I have regular vars that map to column names
However, one is mapped as many-to-one. The child basically contains the ID for the parent. Except in the child I obviously contain the entity of the parent, not the id.

ie: (QUICK simple example....)

```
@ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="bcId",referencedColumnName="id")
private ParentEntityClass theParentClass;
```

How, can I set the the parent object in this hibernate entity so it ONLY uses the parent entity for the ID and doesn't try to save the parent. Should I use Cascade.refresh so it refreshes but doesn't update the parent?

Thanks :)

Comment: If the Parent Object is associated to session then the hibernate will track the changes. if the Parent Object is not in persistent state then you should be fine. provide information about Parent Object State  and provide code

Comment: hmmm I think i might understand what to do... But briefly: when I return from the UI, I might have a new child to add to the parent. Instead of fetching the parent, I was hoping to create a parent and setId then add that to the child.... quick example: setTheParentClass(new ParentEntityClass().setId(parentId));

Essentially just using it for the id for association purposes....

However... should best practice be to fetch the parent and add the child?

Comment: Yes , best Practice is pull the parent object and associate to the child. think about situ, "when you add parent using just id, mean while somebody removing it ( other session) "